# Cannot create property 'key' on string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase and react. I am mapping through the database trying to assign a key to each item. I've done this before and had no problems but for some reason, React doesn't like it. I using componentDidMount to sync my app to firebase and this is where I'm grabbing each item and the unique key from firebase. Also, console.log gives me the correct key I want.

```
 componentDidMount() {
       this.todosRef.on('child_added', snapshot => {
         const todo = snapshot.val();
         todo.key = snapshot.key;
         console.log(todo.key);
         this.setState({ todos: this.state.todos.concat( todo ) });
       });
     }
```

but when I map through the array and assign the key it throws the error : `Cannot create property 'key' on string '`

Here is how I am mapping:

```
const listOfTodos = this.state.todos.map( (todo) => {
    return <li key={todo.key}>{todo}</li>
});
```

Comment: What's the value of `snapshot.val()`? I would suspect it is a string, and trying to set a key on that string with `todo.key = snapshot.key` causes your error.

Comment: Not being entirely sure what `todo` is, why not create a new object containing `todo` and your `key`?

Comment: I have one suggestion.  
Write like this 

   ` let todo = [];
    todo['val'] = snapshot.val();
    todo['key'] = snapshot.key;`

and then use

`const listOfTodos = this.state.todos.map( (todo) => {
    return <li key={todo.key}>{todo.val}</li>
});`

Comment: @Tholle `snapshot.val()` returns each item from the firebase database as a string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe what you have is an immutable object which you're trying to modify.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot

> A DataSnapshot is an efficiently generated, immutable copy of the data at a Database location. 
>   It cannot be modified and will never change (to modify data, you always call the set() method on a Reference directly).

Try putting your todo and key into a new object like this:

```
const todo = { key: snapshot.key, value: snapshot.val() }
```

Comment: This throws the `Objects are not valid as a React child` error.

Comment: You use `todo.val` as a React child. It means that `todo.val` is an object

Comment: I guess I was thinking you'd throw these values into a valid React component.

Comment: This did work now. Did not realize to call `{todo.value}` Thanks to @TomaszBubała for that. Thanks for the help from both of you!